# How to convert an arbitrarily nested object into tabular structure a reversible way?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Given an arbitrarily deep nested object whose structure it not known until runtime, such as

```
    {
      "row-0" : {
        "rec-0" : {
          "date" : 20220121,
          "tags" : [ "val-0" ]
        },
        "rec-1" : {
          "date" : 20220116,
          "url" : "https://example.com/a",
          "tags" : [ "val-0", "val-1" ]
        }
      },
      "row-1" : {
        "rec-0" : {
          "date" : 20220116,
          "url" : "https://example.com/b"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want a tool / program to reversibly convert it to a tabular (2D) structure such as

```
    {
      "row-0" : {
        "['rec-0']['date']" : 20220121,
        "['rec-0']['tags'][0]" : "val-0",
        "['rec-1']['date']" : 20220116,
        "['rec-1']['url']" : "https://example.com/a",
        "['rec-1']['tags'][0]" : "val-0",
        "['rec-1']['tags'][1]" : "val-1"
        },
      "row-1" : {
        "['rec-0']['date']" : 20220116,
        "['rec-0']['url'']" : "https://example.com/b"       
      }
    }
```

This format falicates export as CSV and subsequent editing with a spreadsheet app. The paths of the original nested object are encoded in the keys (column headers) such as `"['rec-0']['date']"` and `"['rec-0']['tags'][0]"` to facilitate the reverse transformation.

What is the best approach to achieving this?

Comment: have you tried something? what goes wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, I didn't try to code a solution because I guessed that a well tested tool / algorithm already existed. Apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done using a simple recursive function that generates a nested key name and end value and populate it into an array.

`Object.entries` is handy in the solution as it can iterate either `array` or `object` using `index` or `key` respectively.

```js
const data = { "row-0": { "rec-0": { date: 20220121, tags: ["val-0"], }, "rec-1": { date: 20220116, url: "https://example.com/a", tags: ["val-0", "val-1"], }, }, "row-1": { "rec-0": { date: 20220116, url: "https://example.com/b", }, }, };

const generateNestedKeyNameAndValue = (input, nestedKeyName, keyValueArr) => {
  if (typeof input === "object") {
    // array or object - iterate over them
    const quoteString = Array.isArray(input) ? "" : "'";
    Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      generateNestedKeyNameAndValue(
        value,
        // extend the key name 
        `${nestedKeyName}[${quoteString}${key}${quoteString}]`,
        keyValueArr
      );
    });
  } else {
    // string or number (end value)
    keyValueArr.push([nestedKeyName, input]);
  }
};

const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
    const generatedKeyValuePairs = [];
    generateNestedKeyNameAndValue(value, "", generatedKeyValuePairs);
    return [key, Object.fromEntries(generatedKeyValuePairs)];
  })
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the current entries using `Array.map()`. Generate the path according to the rules (see `preparePath` function). For each value, check if it's an object (or array). If it is add it's keys to the path. If not, return a `{ [path]: val }` object. Flatten all objects by spreading into `Object.assing()`.

```js
// prepare the key from the current key, isArray(obj), and the previous path
const preparePath = (key, obj, path = []) => [
  ...path, 
  `[${Array.isArray(obj) ? key : `'${key}'`}]`
]

// convert all sub objects to a single object
const fn = (obj, path) => Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([key, val]) => typeof val === 'object' // if the value is an object
    ? fn(val, preparePath(key, obj, path)) // iterate it and it to current path
    : { [preparePath(key, obj, path).join('')]: val } // if the val is not an object, create an object of { [path]: val }
  ))

const data = {"row-0":{"rec-0":{"date":20220121,"tags":["val-0"]},"rec-1":{"date":20220116,"url":"https://example.com/a","tags":["val-0","val-1"]}},"row-1":{"rec-0":{"date":20220116,"url":"https://example.com/b"}}}

// iterate the 1st level of the object since and flatten each sub object
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k, fn(v)])
)

console.log(result)
```